# how to set a postgres user under windows 7

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, passwords

I'm trying to install postgeSQL on my win 7 machine.
trying to set a password during the instalation, I found that I allready have a username 
named postgers in my system. can find it by typing net user postgres in the console.

Now, how can I change it's password?
loged in with my administrator account, I typed "net user postgres abcd123".
the respond is: System error 5 have occurred. Access is denied.

What am I doing wrong? Why my admin account don't have a privilege to modify this user?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a postgres question, but a windows (administrator) question.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening cmd with admin privileges explicitely (Run as administrator in context menu).